# How to get JSONArray exists in another JSONArray?

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have a `JSONArray` contained in another `JSONArray` in a JSON Object like the following:

```
 {
  "protocol": "test",
  "query": [
    {
      "locked": false,
      "ids": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "locked": false
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "locked": false
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "locked": false,
      "ids": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "locked": false
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "locked": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
 }
```

here i want to get the `ids` arrays, i can get the `query` arrays like that:

```
private JSONArray getDB_Query(String json) throws JSONException{

        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Login.errorMessage.setText(sys_err);
        }

        JSONArray query = jsonObj.getJSONArray("query");
        return query;

    }
```

Now if I want to get the ids, is that true :

```
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(query.toString()); // query is the JSONArray I retrieved from the above method

        for(int i= 0; i < query.length(); i ++){
            JSONArray ids_query = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ids");
        }
```

Comment: That JSON Object is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your last for loop like:

```
for(int i= 0; i < query.length(); i ++){
            JSONArray ids_query = query.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("ids");
        }
```